# Extract all information AFTER a comma in a data frame column

Tags: r

How can i extract information AFTER a comma from a data frame column in R?

```
polyname
south dakota,minnehaha
colorado,larimer
nebraska,adams
nebraska,adams
nebraska,adams
```

I want a return column like

```
counties
minnehaha
larimer
adams
adams
adams
```

Comment: Fyi, there is a regex tag you might consider using for this sort of question. Also, R's docs on it are accessible by typing `?regex`. For this case, you might consider `?strsplit`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 df1$counties <- sub('^[^,]+,', '', df1$polyname)
```

Comment: that worked great!. thanks. is there a website where i can find good explanations of regex syntax. I have been experimenting by cannot quite get it.

Comment: @mreth2409 You could check http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html  I would also practise with lots of strings to get a grip on it.

Comment: @mreth2409 I suggest using Perl regex. It is supported by R natively. Just google Perl regex. Also you can paste Regex here http://www.regexr.com/ to have it explained character by character.